# OpenCV taking weird pictures - Java

Tags: java, opencv

I got this headache problem and I can't seem to fix the issue. What I am doing I have a machine that a computer is hooked up too and when ever a condition is true it will take a picture. But the issue is when it does take a picture it sometimes weird, View below. I'v tried inverting the picture but not everything is backward. I looked everywhere... nothing helped me out. I tried many different sample codes they either don't work or still have this issue.

Normal picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCsiP.jpg

Weird Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcmkv.jpg

```
public Mat getCapture(){
    if(camera==null || !camera.isOpened()){
        camera = new VideoCapture(0);
        setCameraValues();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Mat m = null;

    if(!camera.isOpened()){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    else {
        m = new Mat();
        while(true){
            camera.read(m);
            if (!m.empty()){
                //Mat file is not empty
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    camera.release();

    return m;
}
```

Below is sets the camera's settings the focus, zoom, brightness ect.

```
public void setCameraValues()
{
    this.camera.set(28, ((Integer)this.values.get(0)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(27, ((Integer)this.values.get(1)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(10, ((Integer)this.values.get(2)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(11, ((Integer)this.values.get(3)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(12, ((Integer)this.values.get(4)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(15, ((Integer)this.values.get(5)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(20, ((Integer)this.values.get(6)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(33, ((Integer)this.values.get(7)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(34, ((Integer)this.values.get(8)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(3, ((Integer)this.values.get(9)).intValue());
    this.camera.set(4, ((Integer)this.values.get(10)).intValue());
}
```

**EDIT:**
The webcam I am using is Microsoft LifeCam HD

Comment: looks like the colors are inverted?

Comment: I tried inverting the weird picture, it doesn't come close to the normal picture.

Comment: Have you played with the color space? E.g. cv::cvtcolor from HSV to BGR.

Comment: so you say it's only sometimes weird? maybe that's more a hardware problem of your camera? maybe your camera needs some time after activation until correct images are measured? I've seen that on different cameras. Maybe try not to release the camera after each capture. If that solves the problem you can maybe work around the problem.

Comment: I've got another idea: can it happen that two threads are running "at the same time"? Maybe there is a problem when two threads read images at the same time, or maybe (even more probable), if one sets it's parameters while the other thread reads the image?? Please try to add a mutex lock at the beginnging and unlock at the end of the function!!!

Comment: Got back from the great up north for the 4th of July. Thanks for the responses. But what puzzles me is this, I tried it on a desktop computer and it has not gotten a weird picture at at all out of +500 pictures, where on my laptop computer it gives me a weird picture like 20% of the time every 5 pictures 1 is weird. There is no pattern, all random when it does take a weird picture. Just from that I think its a computer hardware issue, but I dont know what different on the laptop compaird to the desktop. DESKTOP: DUO 2, LAPTOP: i5 CORE.    you would think the laptop would win.